# Why is my math on this BMI calculator not working

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++ like three days in and I'm creating a BMI Calculator, I like working out so I thought it would be cool to make. everything with the program works but the math isn't working properly for example I enter my height in inches and my weight in pounds and the bmi number it gives me is wrong every time. The formula is (703 x the weight given/ height squared). can someone help me figure out why its not working. Please don't make fun of my code lol I'm very new and trying to learn C++ Ive never coded before in my life.

Pic of Code:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MZID.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //Variables and Values
    float weight; 
    float height; 
    float bmi;
    //math 
    bmi = (weight*703/height*height);
    //Prompts
    cout << "Please Enter height in inches " << endl;
    cin >> height;
    cout << "Please Enter your weight in pounds " << endl;
    cin >> weight;
    // prompts depending on bei
    if (bmi < 18.5) {
        cout << "Your BMI is " << bmi << "You are underweight" << endl;
    } else if (18.5 < bmi > 24.9) {
        cout << "Your BMI is " << bmi << "You are at a healthy weight" << endl;
    } else if (25 < bmi > 29.9) {
        cout << "Your BMI is " << bmi << "You are overweight" << endl;
    }else if (30 < bmi > 39.9) {
        cout << "Your BMI is " << bmi << "You are obese" << endl;
    } else if (bmi > 40) {
        cout << "Your BMI is" << bmi << "You are severely obese" << endl;
    }

    //Ending
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm expecting to get the right correct answer I usually would in a calculator but I'm not.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: C++ is not a spreadsheet. When you write `bmi = (weight*703/height*height);`, it uses the current values of `weight` and `height`. If those values change in the future, it doesn't change the value stored in `bmi`. At the time you perform the calculation, `weight` and `height` haven't been initialized, so the calculation is performed using garbage values.

Comment: `18.5 < bmi > 24.9` isn't mathematically correct (surely you mean `bmi < 24.9`, not `>`), and it also doesn't do what you'd expect in C++.  Not to mention, what if `bmi` is exactly 18.5? 18.5 is neither less than 18.5 nor greater than 18.5.

Comment: You need to include a [mcve], extracted from your code inline. Also, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: If you're serious about learning C++ then please invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: С++ uses imperative paradigm, i.e. it tells computer to do things in a way as if it would follow order of operations in code. Describing math first, reading values later would be wrong.

Comment: And in maths, weight*703/height*height is equal to weight*703.

Comment: You need to read a basic text on how operators work in C++ because your guess of how they work is *completely wrong*.   `18.5 < bmi > 24.9` does not test if `bmi` is between `18.5` and `24.9`.   It evaluates `18.5 < bmi` first, which produces a `true`/`false` result, and converts that `true`/`false` result to `float` (`true` becomes `1.0`, `false` becomes `0.0`) and tests if *that* exceeds `24.9` (which it never does). `18.5 < bmi > 24.9` therefore ALWAYS tests `false` for any value.  To do the test you (presumably) intend, do `18.5 >= bmi && bmi < 24.9`.

Comment: Also, `bmi = (weight*703/height*height);` does not set up some formula that magically updates `bmi` whenever `weight` or `height` change.     Furthermore, even if you use such a statement correctly,  it is incorrect, since `/` and `*` have equal precedence [as they do mathematically, BTW] so it divides by `height` then multiplies by `height` (i.e. doesn't divide by `height` squared).

Comment: If you had enabled compiler warnings, the compiler would have told you what is wrong with your code.  That would have saved you a trip to StackOverflow.  Also, the compiler would tell you about your other bugs in your program.  However, it would not have told you about the problem with the formula given and `bmi = (weight*703/height/height);` that you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. Statements are executed in the order written, so when you do the calculation the values of all variables are *indeterminate*. And using indeterminate values in any way leads to *undefined behaivor*.

   Do the calculation *after* you have read the input.
2. The conditions are all wrong and not even mathematically correct. Change them all to e.g.

   ```
   cout << "Your BMI is " << bmi << ": ";

   if (bmi < 18.5) {
       cout << "You are underweight\n";
   } else if (bmi < 24.9) {
       cout << "You are at a healthy weight\n";
   } else if (bmi < 29.9) {
       cout << "You are overweight\n";
   } else if (bmi < 39.9) {
       cout << "You are obese\n";
   } else {
       cout << "You are severely obese\n";
   }
   ```

Comment: Now I get what my mistake was. How blind I was not paying attention to that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You calculate BMI correct but not in the right place and your `if` statement isn't correct.

Move BMI calcualtion after user entered inputs.

```
bmi = (weight*703/height*height);
if (bmi < 18.5) {
    ...
} else if ((18.5 >= bmi) && (bmi < 24.9)) {
    ...
} else if ((24.9 >= bmi) && (bmi < 29.9))
...
```

Make it look like this

Comment: No, the BMI isn't calculated correctly. The calculation the OP have will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And your logic in the conditions is flawed as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes you are right about the logic but why BMI calculation  lead to undefined behavior?

Comment: Your logic is still flawed. And what is the value of the variables used in the calculations when it's made?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Now i got what my logic mistake was. but I still disagree with the calculation undefined behavior. What ever the initial values are, the calculation is correct

Answer (score 0):

1. Value of weight, height, should be entered **before** calculation of bmi. That is, line 16 should be moved after cin statements to the line 26.
2. `'if (18.5 < bmi > 24.9)'` and other similar expressions do not do what was intended. They should be written as

   if (18.5 < bmi && bmi < 24.9)

where each condition in [if statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) is clearly separated and combined by [logical and](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical).